# Pandas: Select rows that are null or earlier than today?

Tags: python, pandas

I have to implement the equivalent of the following SQL in a Pandas dataframe:

```
select * from table where ISNULL(date, GETDATE()) >= as_of_date
```

Basically, I want to select the rows where the value of date is more than `as_of_date`. There are some rows where date is `null`, and in those cases, I want to only select those rows if as_of_date is less than or equal to today's date.

Is there a way to do this in Pandas?

Comment: Yes, there is. What have you tried?

Comment: `df[(df.date or date.today()) <= as_of_date)]` returns the error `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.`

Comment: Is `as_of_date` a scalar or another Series?

Comment: its a scalar quantity

Comment: So you mean if `as_of_date` is todays date, you will pick null rows, if not you will drop them?

Comment: Okay, so how do you fill in null values for a column in a Pandas DataFrame?

Comment: In your query you specified `>=` but you said less than in your question, which one do you want?

Comment: My bad. I have edited the question. I want it to be more than.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need:

```
from datetime import date
df[df.date.fillna(date.today()) >= as_of_date]
```

---

You also need to make sure `date` column and `as_of_date` are both datetime objects, if not, use `pd.to_datetime()` to convert:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
as_of_date = pd.to_datetime(as_of_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df[(df['date'] < datetime.now().date()) & (df['date'] == None)]
```

But note this is just an example if you provide same code and df I can help you with greater details.